# AD Operations Master Setup

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a question regarding the "Operations Master" window in AD (see screenshot):
[Operations Master Window Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfKgV.png)

Let's call my active PDC server1. Is it correct to have server2 (also an active server) in the space below?

I thought the second field was to be used if roles were being transferred, but is it used to point to a (possible) PDC backup instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to transfer the role to the server in the second field you would click the Change button. Otherwise, the role is currently held by the server listed in the first field.

Comment: The second field already lists "server2", but is it correct to assume that if the first field lists server1 (PDC), then there's no reason to worry about field 2 listing server2?

Comment: I see what you mean. The "change" option is there so I can set the domain listed in field 2 to grab the role.

Reading comprehension... Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help...